# What is the best way to enable a website users send money to each other?

Tags: paypal

I am working on something that needs to enable the users to send money to each other, is there any platform that can support such operation?

for example: user 1 configures his paypal email address and user 2 makes a small donation!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With PayPal, you can integrate the regular [PayPal Checkout / Smart Payment Buttons](https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/client) , and then add in a `payee` object with an `email_address` parameter, documented here: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/integration-features/custom-payee/

Comment: Thank you very much, I have been looking for this for many days now.