# How to specify a payee with paypal orders api?

Tags: node.js, paypal

Here is the tutorial that I am following: [What is the best way to enable a website users send money to each other?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61935400/what-is-the-best-way-to-enable-a-website-users-send-money-to-each-other)

The problem is with my post request.
Let's break it down into pieces.

1. Headers

```
headers: {
  "Authorization": `Bearer ${accessToken}`,
  "Content-Type": "application/json"
}
```

I get the access token also via paypal api namely https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token.

2. Body

```
body: {
  intent: 'CAPTURE',
  purchase_units: [{
    amount: {
      currency_code: 'USD',
      value: '2.00'
    },
    payee: {
      email_address: "myanothersandboxaccount@gmail.com"
    }
  }]
}
```

But, it doesn't work, as I get an error

```
{
  name: 'INVALID_REQUEST',
  message: 'Request is not well-formed, syntactically incorrect, or violates schema.',
  debug_id: '2884e1b5eccee',
  details: [
    {
      field: '/',
      location: 'body',
      issue: 'INVALID_SYNTAX',
      description: 'MALFORMED_REQUEST_JSON'
    }
  ],
  links: [
    {
      href: 'https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/orders/v2/#error-INVALID_SYNTAX',
      rel: 'information_link',
      encType: 'application/json'
    }
  ]
}
```

curl request

```
curl -v -X POST https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v2/checkout/orders \
-H "Content-Type: application/json" \
-H "Authorization: Bearer A23AALAej8Yg-4iKJBcWckiv5-ZlhYWlkmBsPuWaVngJcMigU7P-6f8P02vnOpIo8QlOJ-P3hd3K86vKo_lpSlu0-bZBj98eg" \
-d '{
  "intent": "CAPTURE",
  "purchase_units": [
    {
      "amount": {
        "currency_code": "USD",
        "value": "100.00"
      },
      "payee": {
        "email": "myanothersandboxaccount@gmail.com"
      }
    }
  ]
}'
```

curl response

```
Note: Unnecessary use of -X or --request, POST is already inferred.
*   Trying 173.0.82.78...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to api.sandbox.paypal.com (173.0.82.78) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /etc/ssl/cert.pem
  CApath: none
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server key exchange (12):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Request CERT (13):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server finished (14):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client key exchange (16):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS change cipher, Change cipher spec (1):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS change cipher, Change cipher spec (1):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* SSL connection using TLSv1.2 / ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256
* ALPN, server did not agree to a protocol
* Server certificate:
*  subject: C=US; ST=California; L=San Jose; O=PayPal, Inc.; OU=PayPal Production; CN=api.sandbox.paypal.com
*  start date: Jul 27 00:00:00 2020 GMT
*  expire date: Aug  1 12:00:00 2022 GMT
*  subjectAltName: host "api.sandbox.paypal.com" matched cert's "api.sandbox.paypal.com"
*  issuer: C=US; O=DigiCert Inc; OU=www.digicert.com; CN=DigiCert SHA2 High Assurance Server CA
*  SSL certificate verify ok.
> POST /v2/checkout/orders HTTP/1.1
> Host: api.sandbox.paypal.com
> User-Agent: curl/7.64.1
> Accept: */*
> Content-Type: application/json
> Authorization: Bearer A23AALAej8Yg-4iKJBcWckiv5-ZlhYWlkmBsPuWaVngJcMigU7P-6f8P02vnOpIo8QlOJ-P3hd3K86vKo_lpSlu0-bZBj98eg
> Content-Length: 212
> 
* upload completely sent off: 212 out of 212 bytes
< HTTP/1.1 201 Created
< Cache-Control: max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate
< Content-Length: 501
< Content-Type: application/json
< Date: Sat, 05 Dec 2020 10:30:13 GMT
< Paypal-Debug-Id: 6bd069526af1c
< 
* Connection #0 to host api.sandbox.paypal.com left intact
{"id":"674004650C383744Y","status":"CREATED","links":[{"href":"https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v2/checkout/orders/674004650C383744Y","rel":"self","method":"GET"},{"href":"https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/checkoutnow?token=674004650C383744Y","rel":"approve","method":"GET"},{"href":"https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v2/checkout/orders/674004650C383744Y","rel":"update","method":"PATCH"},{"href":"https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v2/checkout/orders/674004650C383744Y/capture","rel":"capture","method":"POST"}]}* Closing connection 0
```

And, with curl I get a successful response. I can see that all went well from my paypal sandbox dashboard.

What could it be?

Comment: Your body is correct, which you should be able to verify with command-line curl or postman..  So you'll need to show the full API response (no "...") and possibly also log your request so you can see what's actually being transmitted, since something is wrong but we can't tell what is wrong from the information in your question.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. Just updated the question with the full api response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was using node-fetch to call the paypal api to create an order. Tried with axios, worked just fine.

Answer (score 0):

The error basically means PayPal isn't able to parse the body object it received as JSON, so it appears something is being transmitted/received incorrectly.

You should first test with command-line curl to verify functionality and your JSON's correctness, which should work.

Then to get more details about what's actually going wrong in what you are sending, you will need to log the actual data being sent (not your code, the actual data the code sends when executed)

One way to do this is to instead of sending your request to `https://api-m.paypal.com` , instead send it to a request bin service like offered via https://requestbin.com/